# NullPointerException in AsyncTask OnPostExecute when using ExpandableList

Tags: android

i am try to get post and comment from facebook and display it in ExpandableList but i have the error,
please anyone can help me with this error.............

---

MianActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        private static final String App_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        private static final String App_Secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        ProgressDialog pd;

        String comment;
        List<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


            pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

            new asy().execute("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+App_ID+"&client_secret="+App_Secret+"&grant_type=client_credentials");

        }


        public class asy extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {
            GetData getdata = new GetData();


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return getdata.GetPost(params[0]);

            }



            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd.setTitle("fetching");
                pd.setMessage("watting...");
                pd.show();
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray finalObj = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < finalObj.length(); i++) 
                    {

                        final String message = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                                "message");

                        final String comments = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                        "comments");


                        if(!comments.equals(""))
                        {
                            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(comments);
                            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++)
                            {
                               comment = ja.optJSONObject(j).optString("message");
                               Log.i("comments", comment);
                            }
                        }
                        listDataHeader.add(message);
                        comm.add(comment);
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), comm);

                    }

                        Log.i("size", finalObj.length()+"");


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                    // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


                pd.dismiss();
            }

        }

    }
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

     private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

GetData.java

```
private static final String OWNER_OF_FEED = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    String access_token;
    InputStream is = null;
    String data = "";
    String uri;
    String comment;




    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;



    // to get facebook page post.....
    public String GetPost(String url)
    {



        try {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
            HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
            access_token = EntityUtils.toString(he);

            // access_token contains thing like "access_token=XXXXXXXXXX|YYYYYY" , 
            //need to replace pipe (this is ugly!)
            uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + OWNER_OF_FEED + "/feed?"
           + access_token.replace("|", "%7C");
           Log.i("uri", uri);

           HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
           HttpResponse response = hc.execute(get);
           HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
           is = e.getContent();

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in, 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            Log.i("data", data);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return data;
    }
```

logCat

```
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at com.mamoon.jobforitinjordan.MainActivity$asy.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:114)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at com.mamoon.jobforitinjordan.MainActivity$asy.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-31 01:48:33.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1357):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: listDataHeader.add(message);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listDataHeader` is `null` because you have never initialized it. Change your declaration from

```
List<String> listDataHeader;
```

to

```
List<String> listDataHeader= new ArrayList<String>();
```